# How do I pass value of the variable from controller to view in grails?

Tags: grails, view, controller

I have statuscode that I need to pass from my controller to view. My view code has if/else condition.

```
<g:if test="${code=='something'}">
 <g:link action="StartServer">
    <input type="button" value="Start Server" class="stopimg" id="startServer" />
</g:link>
</g:if>
   <g:else>
       <g:link action="StopServer">
           <input type="button" value="Stop Server" class="runimg" id="stopServer" />
       </g:link>
   </g:else>
```

I need to obtain the `code` from the `controller`, My code value is inside

```
def index() {}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Refer [Model and Views](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/guide/theWebLayer.html#modelsAndViews),  to know how data can be passed from controller to view using model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return everything you need in a map.

```
def index {
...
return [code:variableContainingCode]
}
```